# info buttons not showing in ios6.1

Tags: ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6, ios6.1

I am running Xcode 5.1.1. I have recently been writing an app in Xcode 4. Now I come to develop it further in Xcode 5 I have the following problem. "info Dark" type buttons are no longer visible in IOS6.1 on the phone or simulator. They were before. However they are visible in ios7 on both the phone and simulator. Even though they are invisible on IOS6.1 they will still respond to pressing correctly.

I have checked that they are not somehow behind other views and I have tried altering nearly every possible parameter in story board. I have tried making sure that the buttons are not hidden by programatically setting hidden to NO. If I create a new button I get the same problem. The problem is for "info Light" type buttons also. If I make the buttons custom and give them an image there is no problem.

I can't find anyone with a similar problem on the web.

It occurred to me that the default image for an "info Dark" type button for IOS6.1 was somehow missing in my copy of Xcode but could not work out how to check this. However, I wonder if that is clutching at straws.

Any suggestions would greatly appreciated
Silas

Answer (score 0):

In the "File Inspector" under "Interface Builder Document" I had "Builds for" set to "IOS 6.1 & later". I changed this to "Project Deployment Target (6.1)" and the problem disappeared.

I then went back and reset it back to "IOS 6.1 and later" but could not recreate the problem